# mongo db delete operation on string date deletion

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, python-3.x

i am new to python programming , i have done a mistake while inserting into documents some of the fields are like date is not in the iso date format, i inserted as it is,  and again changed the date format and inserted into mongodb, but there are multiple records with same date feild one is like iso and another one is string date format i want to delete total string formatted objects what i have done is:

`db.attendance.deletemany({date:{$lte:new Date(2016, 12, 22)}})`

I have records like `date:ISODate("2016-12-22T00:00:00.000+0000")`,
i need to delete only string date any one please help me

Comment: And what is a question? Just delete records with particular dates?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is iterate over all values and delete that if it meets your criteria

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.<your_db_name>
for document in db.attendance.find():
    if type(document['date']) == str:
        db.attendance.delete_one(document)
```

Comment: its  nice,can you tell me query i want to perform this action on mongochef

Comment: I haven't worked with mongoshef but, you can use @oblivion 's way to do that in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) as follow:

```
db.attendance.remove("date":{$type:"string"})
```

This will delete all the documents that has `date` stored as `string`. Here `string` is the alias for `String data type` in mongo. In case, you need to perform operations on other data types, you can see [BSON types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)